# Asp.net 3.5 url routing and winforms not working after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

my application not working when I publish (only files needed to run this application) it to the server. I set wildcard mapping in IIS. I'm getting the error below:

HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

In integrated mode, the web.config on my box (2008 R2, IIS7.5) requires **UrlRoutingModule** to be added to the system.webserver/modules section and **UrlRoutingHandler** to be added to the system.webserver/handlers (as in many of the examples I have seen posted). The routing *refuses to work* if UrlRoutingModule is added to !

Answer (score 0):

So are you saying that your code only doesn't work when you upload the published version of your application?

Are you pre-compiling the application or getting the server to do it?

Can you hit a .html page directly and a .aspx page directly?

Sounds like you are deploying to IIS 6, here are my IIS6 deployment notes for one of my apps which is 3.5 with url routing:

```
Add read / write
Add Default Application to Application name
Under configuration add a wild card mapping: add aspnet_isapi.dll, untick verify that file exists

Change ASP.NET version to 2.0

Under directory security add IUSR Anonymous and password. 

make sure the directory has ASPNet user and IUSR accounts added in security folder tab.. v important
```

Hope this helps!